# Easy basis vector question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a really easy Linear algebra question i'm just wondering if someone could explain how this solution was obtained?

https://gyazo.com/7cde65dff654e736dafc6097d0aa7ddb

All i'm wondering is how they have obtained that basis vector?

Thanks for any help guys apologies if there are any issues this is my first time on this website!

Comment: What is the question? In that screenshot they seem to be giving the solution, assuming the reader already knows what problem they're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer, Using C8 given at the beginning how do they then obtain the basis vectors given below

Comment: Please avoid inserting links in your question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial where you can learn to typeset math equations.

Comment: @Sam that's a very big matrix.  Demanding that the asker type out the entire thing is a bit much.

Comment: How do they obtain the "basis vectors"? Basis vectors for _what_ space?

Comment: The basis vectors for C8

Comment: As far as I can tell from the picture, $C8$ is a _matrix_. There's no such thing as a basis for a matrix; a matrix is not a vector space.

Comment: What is the subject area here? Error correcting codes or something like that? You need to provide more context as your subject area may use nomenclature differently from standard mathematics.